During layoffs or mass layoffs, is it common for the selection process to be random?
During a mass layoff of at least 10% of a company, the VP told the remaining employees after the layoff, briefly and causally, that the selection process of who got laid off was random.
Can this statement be believed?
Is this common?
What about, the possibility of at least some aspects of the selection is in fact random, may be not entire?

Very dependent on country. There are usually rules.

Can you write anything about the random selection process here if management reveals it? I am curious.

Random? Doubt it. Or at least the "good" employees weren't in the selection pool of randoms. They're just trying to placate the situation. They might even be trying to see which remaining employees take solace in believing it was random because it helps to reveal those who should be cut in the next round.

It would be interesting whether all employees, including the CEO and their staff are in the pool. Otherwise there is a non-random way to select the pools.

Layoffs are never random. A particular individual's presence on the list certainly might appear to be.

Only if the business is truly run by idiots. Saying the layoffs were random - assuming they they think anyone buys it - means they don't think much of the people they are saying it to. What is there is gain by telling somebody that stays - just luck, not performance we kept you? The only slight possible benefit is if they can BS people that they laidoff by saying it wasn't their performance. But why? Sleezy at best.

Walter Isaacson reports how Elon and his "musketeers" laid off all but maybe 150 of the 2500 developers at Twitter after the takeover ("if each of them wrote only 3 lines of code per day, that would make 3 million lines of code per year, enough for a whole OS. I feel like I'm in a comedy show here"). It took them 3 days. They looked only at the most productive ones by lines of code; of these, they looked at the actual code they had committed, its quality and relevance. That is certainly one extreme, but it did happen.

@DogBoy37: If it's observably random then it's saying don't bother with a wrongful termination lawsuit. But just claiming it is won't accomplish that.

There may be a random factor once they have picked out a list of those whom they would least miss. It would not be completely random across the entire employee base, but you wouldn't expect it to be.

I would imagine that if there were multiple layoffs, all of the fat would be trimmed when you get to the last layoff and you could legitimately do random layoffs.  Even then, "Who joined the company/team last?" is usually the default goto.  You could make it random to hit some higher-salaried workers since the last to join is often your cheapest employees.

I would imagine that by the time all the back-room negotiating and compromising was done, it certainly FELT like it was random.

If the layoff is voluntary, it could look like a random layoff.  Bullying and pressuring for voluntary layoff could also look random.

IMHO, the worst is to be one of the people who stayed.  The lingering thought is not that people will be laid off, but when.  It is difficult to work for a company when you don't know how much time you have remaining there.

Its about as random as a cop "randomly" pulling over a combi to "check for drugs"

I worked for a customer, and when the customer went into problems, they put all the names in a "basket", including all managers. They picked the required number of names, and they went away. One day, a quite-high-level manager said "good bye", the same as several other people, with different jobs. There were several rounds of lay-offs, all executed in the same manner. I think that while random picking is rare, it definitely exists - as a minimum, the example above.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica "Lines of code" is a notoriously bad measure of productivity.

@DaveG Of course (but it becomes real bad if people know it to be a measure). That's why they then looked at the quality to get the intersection, true high performers. They probably missed a few that didn't make the quantitative cut, people who made only a few but extremely important commits. But applying the quantity criteria first could be done with a script that narrowed the set down to a size that could be examined manually. The other way around was not feasible.


Can this statement be believed?

I have severe doubts. No one is going to lay off their top performers if there are poor performers to get rid off first.

Is this common?

No. I've been (unfortunately) through my fair share of these and in all cases a lot of thinking and process were involved in creating "the list". This is usually governed by performance and relevance to the business. A strong performer in an important business role has (in my experience) always been safe.
These being said, almost all of this happens behind closed doors and the rationale and details are rarely communicated to the employee base at large.

What about, the possibility of at least some aspects of the selection is in fact random, may be not entire?

IMO that is highly likely. It would be extremely unusual to just role the dice. There is maybe some small amount of randomness after the first list has been created and there are more names on it than need to be terminated. However, I have NEVER seen this happening.

Depending on where you are in the world, the decision on who is fired might also be based on years in the company or family status/ number of dependents. These criteria can be completely independent of performance but they are not random either.

In my experience, the expensive people were laid off first or given separation packages, depending on time served.  Next would be duplicates.  And finally experts that not needed.  Never heard of, nor experienced, random selection.

LOL.  In 2010 or so FedEx used a consulting company to figure out how to trim their IT department.  They came up with "those in their positions less than 1 year".  So all those top performers, that were recently promoted, were laid off.

Given that the OP has stated no country, you may want to prefix your anwer with the countries that you know this applies to. Almost any statement in the answer would be wrong and illegal where I live. That doesn't make it a bad answer per se, but it needs that context.


Can this statement be believed? Is this common?

I wouldn't believe it.
Every place I have ever worked that had layoffs specifically chose the folks to keep and those to part ways with.
It only makes sense. Assuming you want a viable, healthy company on the other side of a layoff, why risk getting rid of your best people? And why basically tell the remaining people that in the next round of layoffs they may also be gone, no matter how hard they work or what work success they have?
If they actually chose layoff candidates at random, then they are too stupid to work for, IMHO. If I were one of the workers that survived that round of layoffs, I'd get out as quickly as I could.

And what constitute "best people" to keep is not necessarily individual performance. Sometimes, it means how well the person is liked by others or how well they fit into the team. A "high performing" person who makes life difficult for the rest is likely to be laid off.

Anything is possible. Layoffs are really hard. They are made even harder by the fact that people don't have a single "performance score". One person might be great at skill A and so-so at skill B, and another good but not great at both. If the layoffs are part of a transition not to do skill A any more (outsourcing it or getting out of that part of the business) then you should lay off the person who is great at A, who in general might be your highest performer, because skill A is no longer relevant.
Some places don't try to predict which aspects of your performance will be more relevant in the future, but just go by seniority - in some cases to the day (I know because I have, on more than one occasion, been asked to fix HR software that didn't [correctly] display seniority to the day.)
Still others will drop entire locations, or entire departments, or ask for volunteers. They will keep people for having the most different skills (eg how many programming languages you can work in) rather than being best at any one of them. They will spread the pain around by saying "4 from each of these 10 groups" rather than one group of 40 being laid off entirely. Could I believe that someone would say "we need to drop 1 in 5 people from [large group such as a location]" and then choose them randomly? I could, yes. It's quick and it carries less emotional burden than arguing with each other about who will be more useful to the company or who needs their job more.
There is no fair way to lay someone off. They wanted that job and were counting on it. It can hurt those doing the choosing (and having to carry on afterwards without the laid off people) as much as those who are chosen. I might not advise someone to do what your VP is claiming was done, but I have no trouble believing it.

At one place we were told: If you volunteer to leave then you can leave without compensation and the number of people laid off stays unchanged. So there is one less person employed afterwards.

Whereas I worked somewhere that offered roughly double the legally required severance to those who volunteered, and we were told it would reduce the number of layoffs, possibly to zero. (I don't know if that happened or not because I left, but I know they had avoided layoffs with this approach some years earlier.)

This is a much more grounded answer than the "this never happens" ones above. Layoffs are chaotic, often highly regulated, and emotionally charged. I wouldn't bet any amount of money against people being picked from a list with a random number generator at some point in the process.

If you give the layoff size as a percentage, you must be working for a large corporation with multiple levels of management.
It is relatively common to aim for minimization of:

The total duration of the process from the point when its preparation hits the grapevine till when all the survivors know they are survivors.
Any stigmatization of the laid off colleagues as low performers.
The double stress to the management layers responsible for selection AND execution of the layoff.  (And then also for the inevitable coping with the same workload having fewer resources on their team.)

An initial random or otherwise fully mechanical selection of specific individuals to terminate by company leadership is believable.  That way of launching the operation may partly alleviate all of the three concerns above, even if the degree to which the lower management is then allowed to make quick substitutions ("exceptions") within their area of responsibility can effectively negate all the randomness or crudeness of the outcome.

The only scenarios I can think of where it might make sense to be truly random would be:

Union contracts - if the company is forced to be random because of previous union negotiations.
Weird legal/jurisdictional issue - you can't be accused of bias/discrimination, if you can prove it was totally random.
If the role is low skill / high turn over anyway - i.e. the company is used to recruiting and training a particular job, since it's difficult to retain someone in that role for any length of time.

That said I don't see the value in an executive stating a RIF is random without further clarification, since high (or higher) performing employees will have no motivation to continue working hard, since it won't impact their survivability in future layoffs, assuming the future layoff will also be random.

I've been through several layoffs. In the USA, I have never heard of it being random. That would be incredibly stupid. They'll generally whack by seniority, entire departments, and by manager discretion.
HR reviews all decisions to make sure the ball doesn't land in the same cup too often, even if it should.
